# Knockout submit binding on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to get text entered in an input box to apply to the page on click of a button.  I am using the submit binding, but can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<form data-bind="submit: doSomething">
<label>
  <input data-bind='value: showText' />
</label>
  <button type="submit">button</button>
</form>
  <h1><span data-bind='text: fullText'> </span></h1>
```

**JS:**

```
var ViewModel = function(text) {
  this.showText = ko.observable(text);

  this.doSomething : function(formElement) {

    this.fullText = ko.computed(function(){
      return this.showText();
    }, this);
 }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error:

```
this.doSomething : function(formElement) {
```

should be

```
this.doSomething = function(formElement) {
```

Second error:

```
this.fullText
```

is defined inside the function, but you use it in binding to viewModel.

I've prepared [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjcv86pt/) with fixed code.